# Finding the source of a redirect call in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

A Codeigniter application I inherited has a 302 redirect taking it away from the https url. The redirect does not occur if directly visiting the http url. My question is, "Where might this redirect be taking place?

I can land on the https site if I break the script execution up to the construct function of the specific controller called. Doing the same thing in the index function will land back on the http site.

I decided to try skipping "exit" and simple echo something before the redirect to see where the error points to and it refers me to the url helper, redirect function. I cannot tell where that helper method was called from.

Forcing ssl with the .htaccess causes a redirect loop, so I have to fix this redirect problem first.

While the example below is the Login controller, the problem happens regardless of which controller is called.

The login controller:

```
class login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mod_login');
        $this->load->helper('date');
        echo "You are here.";// **This is the last place I can cut execution and land on an https site.
        exit;
    }

    function index() {
    }
}
```

Any help on where to look will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

**I found the location of the redirect.** When searching through all of the config files I found a spot that set $config['enable_hooks'] = true. When I found the hooks folder, there is an ssl_helper that has two methods: force_ssl and unforce_ssl. I still have to research codeigniter hooks, but commenting out the code inside the unforce_ssl method has fixed everything in the mean time while I try to figure out why my predecessor did it this way, and what the right way to disable this is.

EDIT 4-5-2017
Thanks DFriend for spending time looking in to the problem.
If a break happens in this specific place, after the controller construct and before the controller method, then the problem is with a hook. This can be found in "system/core/Codeigniter.php" between lines 312 and 322.

Comment: Is the `exit;` call yours or was it there?

Comment: Mine. I place it there in my debugging attempts. That is the last place I can exit the script and still land on the https site.

Comment: OK, good. Not sure I understand your problem. Let's see. You browse to `https://examle.com` but end up on `http://example.com`. Is that right?

Comment: That's right. This is particular to some inner working of Codeigniter which is a php mvc framework. If you're familiar with Codeigniter you could hopefully tell me which file to look at. If you aren't very familiar with Codeigniter it would be impossible to be much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to look is in `application/config/config.php` where there is an item called `$config['base_url']` it will look something like this.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Notice the protocol at the start of that string. If you always want to use `https` then change the string accordingly. The string MUST contain the protocol by the way.

Codeigniter allows multiple `config.php` files. If this inherited app is using them they will be in subfolders of `application/config/`. If this option is being used then the subfolders will be named "production" and "development". Conceivably there may be only one subfolder. In it (them) you will probably find additional `config.php` files. Check these `$config['base_url']` value(s) too.

The other thing to look for is any/all calls to the helper function `base_url` ([documented here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url)). It accepts an optional second argument (string) defining the protocol to use - 'http' or 'https'.

Search your source code for calls to the helper function `redirect` ([Documented here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)). The may be specifying the protocol in the first argument (URI string).

If you still haven't found it then search source code "http" and maybe you'll find the protocol being forced on you in some other way.

The set of files to examine first are those located in `application/controllers` then try `application/libraries` then `application/models` then `application/views`. The last is very unlikely. If none of those has what your looking for work your way though this list of the `application/` subdirectories

1. core
2. hooks
3. helpers
4. includes
5. any other folders you can find :)

Good luck. It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Thank you. I ran through each of those in the process of arriving at the controller itself. In just the last few minutes I found there is an ssl_helper inside the hooks folder. I don't know where the ssl_helper unforce_ssl is called from, but for now I disabled it and everything is working.

Comment: If you edit your answer to suggest I look in the application/hooks folder I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: That helper is not part of the CI install. Obviously something custom and useless in your case I suppose. Took your suggestion - see edited answer.

Comment: Now you get to search all those places for calls to `ssl_helper unforce_ssl ` and remove them. You're getting paid by the hour right?

Comment: Thank you. You're right that no one could have ever guessed it. The project is a bit of a mess. Thank God it's by the hour. The fact they didn't have an ssl on a service that requires a log in gives some sense of the state of the issue.